# How to block message sound alert?

Tags: android

i am writing a video player application. In mobile devices, my video's audio is disturbing by message alert sound. So i wanna block message alert sound and continue to play my video's audio as usually. How can i do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following to suppress notification-

add receiver intent filter in your AndroidManifest file.

```
<receiver android:name=".SMSReceiver">
       <intent-filter android:priority="100">
              <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />                  
       </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Setting a high number in priority, such as 100. The higher the number, the earlier Android executes your application. So in this case, when an incoming message is received, your application will execute first, and you can decide what to do with the message. To prevent other applications from seeing the message, simply call the `abortBroadcast()` method in your broadcast receiver-

```
this.abortBroadcast();
```

Comment: hi Yup.. Actually what i am expecting is, Just i wanna disable all incoming sms notification(i.e sms sound alert) while running my app. So how can i do that?

Comment: Thanks Yup.. It is working. 50% work done. But this.abortBroadcast(); statement completely deleting my SMS. What i want is just i want to stop sound of that SMS alert and i wanna receive SMS as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to talk notifications (push), i think the solution is play an empty sound :(

like that :

```
notification.sound = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + context.getPackageName() + "your_empty_file_sound.mp3");
```

I hope that help you.